# How to convert an array expressed in string form to actual array

Tags: ruby

I have an array that is in string form

```
"[{"img_type":"HA","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"},{"img_type":"HB","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}]"
```

I need to convert that to

```
[
  {"img_type": "HA", "img_size": 0, "img_name": "8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}, 
  {"img_type": "HB", "img_size": 0, "img_name": "8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}
]
```

I tried removing double quotes, but it didn't work. How can I convert this to an array?

Comment: you can try `eval`

Comment: Start by replacing the surrounding double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: @uzaif WUT? please never ever suggest such a weird stupid solutions for what can be done properly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland why have you removed your answer? It’s absolutely correct AFAICT.

Comment: @mudasobwa, after posting I noticed that the OP wants the keys to be symbols rather than strings. I fixed it and undeleted.

Comment: you can do something like `JSON.parse(str).map(&:symbolize_keys)` in Rails

Comment: "How can I convert this to an array?" – You can convert it by writing a program which converts it. If you encounter a problem with this program, you carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, and libraries you are using, single-step through the code in a debugger, write tests, trace the execution with pen&paper, and if you still can't figure out the problem … wait a week and then start with fresh eyes and a fresh mind. Then, and only then, if you still have problems, you can read up on how to construct a [mcve] and write a narrow, specific, focused question on [so].

Comment: @RaviMariya, since posting my answer I noticed that (in pure Ruby) `JSON::parse` allows `:symbolize_names` to be included as an optional parameter. Hence, no need for `map`.

Comment: @cary, great, didn't know about that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = '[{"img_type":"HA","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"},{"img_type":"HB","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}]'
```

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse(str, symbolize_names: true)
  #=> [{:img_type=>"HA", :img_size=>0, :img_name=>"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"},
  #    {:img_type=>"HB", :img_size=>0, :img_name=>"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}]
```

Notice that [JSON::parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) provides for several optional parameters, one of which (`symbolize_names`) "returns symbols for the names (keys) in a JSON object. Otherwise strings are returned."

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys → `JSON.parse(str).map { |g| g.transform_keys(&:to_sym) }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, since posting I discovered that `JSON#parse` takes an optional parameter `:symbolize_names`, which appears to be just what is needed. Thought you might like to know.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
str = '[{"img_type":"HA","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"},{"img_type":"HB","img_size":0,"img_name":"8a040ff1-e780-4843-9f01-6dc37e11f3c8"}]'
array = eval(str)
```

This may solve your purpose but its nasty to use eval as it brings serious danger of undefined methods and SQL injection.

Prefer [`JSON.parse(your_string)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)for this purpose.

Comment: Downvoted because, while it does produce the correct result, it does not mention the serious dangers of using `eval`.

Comment: Thanks @Max, I've added the some drawbacks of using eval.